# Relative position causing content to come on top of nav-bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that has its position `fixed`. If i give the content of the body position `relative` it is causing that content to move over the navbar, instead of moving underneath the navbar. I tried giving `navBar` higher `z-index` values, but that didn't work out. Is there any workaround? (Using `transform(translate())` is also causing the content with that style applied to come on top.)

P.S. Giving `z-index` of -1 to the contents who has either `relative` positioning or has `transform` applied can make the content to go beneath. But then, I have to apply that to all the contents of the page. So I would prefer something that can be done easier.

I have added some dummy code to illustrate the issue. I would like the content to go beneath the `navbar` by changing the css of just the `navbar` because I have a lot of content in reality and changing all the code would be difficult.

[Code  to illustrate the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/y9q6e7nm/)

Comment: share the code instead of describing it, we will better see the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif have added some code to illustrate the issue

Comment: you can simply give z-index to navbar https://jsfiddle.net/y9q6e7nm/1/ .. it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello my friend  i thing this code might be better then yourse  check it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>exircice</title>
 <!--styling -->
 <style type="text/css"> 
 .navbar 
 {
  background-color: red;
  width:100vw;
    position: fixed;
   left: 0;
    right: 0;height:40px;
    z-index: 2;
 }

.content 
 {
    position: relative;
   top: 45px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1;
 }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--navbar -->
 <div class="navbar">
  <p>text here</p>
 </div>

 <!--navbar -->
 <div class="content"> <!--navbar -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```